# Hide soft keyboard on application load

Tags: android, keyboard, load, hide, android-edittext

I have an application with an `EditText` element on the main view.
This means that when my application is loaded the soft keyboard appears per default.

I would like to be able to hide the keyboard on load, 
so it does not show until i tap on the `EditText` view.

How do i manage this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can do something easier. Add this to the LinearLayout (or any other layout that is the root):

```
<LinearLayout
...
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
...
/>
```

Comment: The accepted answer didn't work for me, I already had stateHidden set.  This suggestion works.  I applied it to the XML layout instead:  android:focusable="true" and android:focusableInTouchMode="true" on a parent view group.

Answer (score 5):

```
InputMethodManager imm = 
    (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

This will hide in all situations (even when the EditView has focus):

```
 EditText editView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextConvertValue);
 editView.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can hide keyboard when page open easily**

> Add these two properties on root layout

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

> Sample code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
```