# EditText is covered by Keyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am having a EditText in the hierarchy of

```
<CoordinateLayout>
...
    <NestedScrollView>
    ...
        <RelativeLayout> <!-- This is inside an included xml layout -->
        ...
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/rateCalculator"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="5"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:paddingLeft="60dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </NestedScrollView>
</CoordinateLayout>
```

The `EditText` is being covered by the android soft-keyboard when it is being on focus! So I am unable to see what is being typed while typing!

**Update:**

This is my manifest code. Doesn't help!

```
<activity
        android:name=".OfferRide"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_offer_ride"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Depending on behavior you want to get, you can use android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" or android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" on your activity declaration in Manifest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the `gravity` from the `EditText` made it! It seems to be a bug.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/rateCalculator"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:maxLength="5"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:paddingLeft="60dp" />
```

Comment: I think it's not a bug, it's a typo mistake or something perhaps you didn't see or mistake on writing, but, my answer worked with removing that gravity?

Comment: Well, nothing works other than removing gravity! I did a research over the internet, and it says this is a bug! @LinX64 thanks for your effort.

Comment: Agree that this is a bug. Also I observed that android:inputType and android:gravity cannot be together. So the solution is to remove one of it.

Comment: Also found solution for password inputType. So you can remove android:inputType="textPassword" and set it in code like this:

mEtPassword.setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());
keyboard works fine now

Answer (score 2):

**Here is the full doc:** http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft

```
android:windowSoftInputMode=["stateUnspecified",
                                       "stateUnchanged", "stateHidden",
                                       "stateAlwaysHidden", "stateVisible",
                                       "stateAlwaysVisible", "adjustUnspecified",
                                       "adjustResize", "adjustPan"] >
```

> How the main window of the activity interacts with the window
>   containing the on-screen soft keyboard. The setting for this attribute
>   affects two things: The state of the soft keyboard — whether it is
>   hidden or visible — when the activity becomes the focus of user
>   attention. The adjustment made to the activity's main window — whether
>   it is resized smaller to make room for the soft keyboard or whether
>   its contents pan to make the current focus visible when part of the
>   window is covered by the soft keyboard. The setting must be one of the
>   values listed in the following table, or a combination of one
>   "state..." value plus one "adjust..." value. Setting multiple values
>   in either group — multiple "state..." values, for example — has
>   undefined results. Individual values are separated by a vertical bar
>   (|). For example:

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize" . . . >
```

> Values set here (other than **"stateUnspecified"** and
>   **"adjustUnspecified"**) override values set in the theme.

Flags:

- "stateUnspecified"
- "stateUnchanged"
- "stateHidden" - The state of the soft keyboard — whether it is hidden or visible — when the activity becomes the focus of user attention.
- "stateAlwaysHidden"
- "stateVisible"
- "stateAlwaysVisible"
- "adjustUnspecified"
- "adjustResize"

Or sometimes java will do that:

```
EditText edtView=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextConvertValue);
    edtView.setInputType((InputType.TYPE_NULL);
```

Take a look:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6122733/4409113

Comment: Doesn't help! It is still the same!

Comment: I found the answer. the `gravity` in the `EditText` is the reason for the bug. Removing that helps! I am answering it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try adjustPan, adjustResize options available for windowSoftInputMode in your AndroidManifest as follows:

```
<activity
    ...
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
</activity>
```

You can learn more about it from [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft)

Comment: I think the problem is due to the NoActionBar, theme, making activity fullscreen affects the working of adjustpan, resize.. functionality.. refer this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558810/adjustpan-not-preventing-keyboard-from-covering-edittext)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on behavior you want to get, you can use android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" or android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" on your activity declaration in Manifest.